# Copy cells to another sheet if row contains '1'

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with ten pages. I need to auto fill sheet `Report` if sheet `David` contains `1` in column I. I need to copy cells C14:C34, J14:J34 and L1:L34 only if there is a `1` in column I.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to auto fill sheet Report if sheet David contains "1" in column "i". I need to copy cells C14 - C34, J14 - J34 and L14 - L34 only if there is "1" in column "i"

In the sheet where you want to put the data (I think that's sheet Report), put this formula into C14

```
= if('David'!$I$14=1, 'David'!C14, "")
```

then copy and paste it into C15-C34, J14 - J34 and L14 - L34.

This will make those cells in Report blank (i.e., "") if your condition is not met, or the value from David if it is.

Note the $ signs:  these say to use absolute cell references instead of relative ones, so that copy/pasting formulas will work.   I'm not sure from your question if you want to look at i14 every time, or just the contents of column I in the matching row.   If the latter, then remove the $ sign before the row number.

See a worked example here:   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tma5P-bjB4P7KtXiR2GMvjvG5fvAbOKGHpQyZqadC5A/edit?usp=sharing